# Vertical alignment of cell content in tabular

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, alignment

In LaTeX, when I write something like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \hline
  asdf &
  $ \begin{alignedat}{10}
      a +  b & = c    \\
      c      & = b+ a
    \end{alignedat} $ \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

I get the following result:

[image: Result of LaTeX code]

How can I align "asdf" to the top instead of the vertical centre of the cell? Ideal would be if this could somehow be done by manipulating it in the tabular options, the way I can adjust it with the `l`-thing, perhaps by creating a new type with the `\newcolumntype` command.

Comment: `\begin{alignedat}[t]`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you very much for this quick and helpful anwer! Not the first time you are helping me out I believe! If you write it as an answer I can mark it a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\begin{alignedat}[t]` so the reference point of the alignment is on its top row, so that aligns with the reference point of the first column (which is on its baseline)

Comment: Thanks a lot, also for the explanation. Worked perfectly!